# How exactly are linear and rotational velocity and acceleration related?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I understand that distance is always a postive number, so its derivative, speed, is also always positive. However, for rotational motion with angles, it seems that $\Delta \theta$ can have a sign, clockwise negative and counterclockwise positive.

1. When we differentiate $s = \theta r$ ($s$ being the arc length, so therefore it's a distance not a displacement), $\frac{ds}{dt}$ must be speed (distance over time), but $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ will give angular velocity, which can be negative since $\Delta \theta$ can be negative. However, according to my knowledge, speed cannot be negative, so $v = \omega r$ does not make sense to me.
2. Even worse, if I blindly ignore this and follow the textbook and differentiate this again with respect to time, it says I get $a = \alpha r$, which is even more confusing because i just differentiated *speed* over time, which I know can't be an acceleration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing the difference between speed and velocity.

Comment: By my knowledge, velocity is a displacement vector differentiated over time, and speed is its magnitude. I still get the same problem.

Comment: Velocity is ${\bf v}=d{\bf x}/dt$ and even in one dimension $dx$ can be negative just as $d\theta$ can be negative. In $s=\theta r$ both $s$ and $\theta$ can have either sign. This why $\omega$ is called the angular *velocity* not the angular speed.

Comment: I understand, but this does not seem to answer my original question. So is ds/dt in fact a velocity and not speed (which I originally assumed it to be?)

Comment: When you do calculation you have to take one reference frame. In a circle there be a direction, just like in a segment.

Comment: $s$ is the coordinate from origin.

Comment: You need to define an analog of *distance* for rotations.   Your $\theta$ is the analog of displacement, so it behaves like displacement.  You don't have an analog of distance.  You are using the variable $\theta$ to represent both angular distance and angular displacement.

Comment: @garyp If so, ds/dt *must* be a velocity because θ is analog to displacement, not distance. However, s, arc length, does not show the shortest length between two points on a circle. Therefore it cannot be a displacement. And now nothing makes sense...

Comment: @mikeeei s shows the shortest length between two points ALONG the circle. Because, here your motion is along the circle, i.e. along the perimeter of the circle

Comment: Are you comparing motion along the arc of a circle and motion on a straight line chord between two points on a circle?  If   so you are really trying to describe what an apple tastes like by comparing it to the taste of an orange.  Constrain your circular motion to a circle.  Note that motion in a circle can be described using the rectilinear concepts, but the math is a lot more complicated than what you are trying to do.

Comment: @garyp If s is analog to displacement, for v = ωr, shouldn't v be named tangential velocity? Why does my textbook (and a lot of other sources) call it linear speed? That was originally the reason I had assumed s is analog to distance, and not displacement.

Comment: You are correct about that.  Your careful reading has run you right into the very common practice of not carefully distinguishing speed from velocity. Very often a textbook will define *speed* and *velocity* and then proceed to use them interchangeably.  The book I'm teaching from right now does exactly that.  You have to get used to discerning what is meant from context.

Answer (score 1):

Since s is a vector ds/dt or velocty v  is a vector, so it has direction in two or three space, the same with angular velocity . When you write = a,  and r are usually vectors, it seems you look at very simple cases only, where all the vectors have only one direction.

Comment:  = , so how can arc length be a vector?

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to work in polar coordinates with the basis unit vectors $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$. Then there is no confusion about positive and negative signs-- the particle's position, velocity, and acceleration are firmly defined as vectors. For general motion in a plane (not necessarily circular, $r$ can vary with time), you can show that
$$\vec{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$$
and
$$\vec{a} = (-r\dot{\theta}^2+\ddot{r})\hat{r} + (r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})\hat{\theta}$$
For a detailed derivation check out this link (pg. 32): [https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~zcapd49/phas1247coursenotes.pdf](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Ezcapd49/phas1247coursenotes.pdf)

When $r$ is held constant, we get equations of the same form as those you mentioned:
$$\vec{v}=r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$$
and
$$\vec{a}=-r\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r} + r\ddot{\theta}\hat{\theta}.$$
So we see that $r\alpha$ is only the tangential component of the acceleration.

Notes:

- Just in case you aren't familiar with it, a dot over a variable is another notation for the time derivative of the variable, e.g., $\dot{r} = \frac{\,dr}{\,dt}$. Similarly for a double dot: $\ddot{r}=\frac{\,d^2r}{\,dt^2}$.
- $\hat{r}$ is the radial unit vector; it points outward from the origin to the position of the particle and has magnitude one. $\hat{\theta}$ is the counterclockwise tangential unit vector. It points perpendicular to the line connecting the particle's position with the origin, in a ccw sense. As with all unit vectors, it has magnitude one. (If you already know this, just ignore it.)

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/537796/254821) for a detailed discussion of the following kinematical analysis in the context of orbital motion.

$\underline{\textit{Analysis:}}$

Let $\vec{r}$ be the displacement of the material particle $P$ from the material particle designated to be the origin, $\vec{v}^R_P:=\vec{v} := \frac{{}^Rd}{dt}\vec{r} := \dot{\vec{r}}$ and $\vec{a}_P^R:=\vec{a} := \frac{{}^Rd^2}{dt^2}\vec{r} := \ddot{\vec{r}}$ be the velocity and acceleration of the material particle calculated using the reference frame $R$, respectively. Further, we denote the time derivative of a vector calculated using the reference frame $R$ by $\dot{(\cdot)}:=\frac{{}^Rd}{dt}(\cdot)$. Denoting $r:=|\vec{r}|$ and $\hat{r} := \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}$, we can see that $\dot{|\hat{r}|} := \frac{d |\hat{r}|}{dt} = \dot{1} = 0 = \frac{1}{2} \hat{r} \cdot \dot{\hat{r}}$, which implies that $\dot{\hat{r}} \perp \hat{r}$. Further, $\vec{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\hat{r}}$ and $\vec{a}=\ddot{r}\hat{r}+2\dot{r}\dot{\hat{r}}+r\ddot{\hat{r}}$.

Let us calculate the time derivative using a reference frame $M$ rotating but not translating w.r.t. the reference frame $R$ such that an axis of $M$ always passes through the material particle and let us denote the angular velocity and speed of $M$ w.r.t. $R$ by $\vec{\omega}^{MR}:=\vec{\omega}$ and $\frac{{}^Rd}{dt}\vec{\omega}^{MR}:=\vec{\alpha}$ respectively. Then, [the Coriolis' theorem](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec08.pdf) implies that $\vec{v}_P^R:=\vec{v}=\frac{{}^Md}{dt}\vec{r}+\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+\vec{\omega}\times r\hat{r}$. Since $\vec{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\hat{r}}$, we obtain that $\vec{\omega}\times \hat{r}=\dot{\hat{r}}$ so that the unit vectors $\hat{r},\frac{\dot{\hat{r}}}{\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})},\frac{\vec{\omega}}{|\vec{\omega}|}$ constitute a unit right handed traid (which can be) associated with the reference frame $M$ (this reference frame is *instantaneously* defined at each time instant in the duration of motion of $P$ and mimics a rigid body although no such real-world rigid body may be associated with it).

Let us now assume that the motion of $P$ is planar. Due to the assumption of the planar motion, the vector $\frac{\vec{\omega}}{|\vec{\omega}|}$ is identical to the *constant unit vector* $\hat{k}$ which is normal to the plane of motion determined by the linearly independent pair $\hat{r},\dot{\hat{r}}$ and we can write $\vec{\omega}=\dot{\theta}\hat{k}$ where $\theta$ denotes the angular position of $P$ (which is identical to the scalar angular displacement of the reference frame $M$ w.r.t. the reference frame $R$) in it's plane of motion. Therefore, $\vec{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\hat{r}}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\theta}\frac{\dot{\hat{r}}}{\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})}$ so that $\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})=\dot{\theta}$ and $\vec{a}=\ddot{r}\hat{r}+2\dot{r}\dot{\hat{r}}+r\ddot{\hat{r}}=(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{r}+(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{\theta}\dot{r})\frac{\dot{\hat{r}}}{\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})}$ so that $\ddot{\hat{r}}=-\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r}+r\ddot{\theta}\frac{\dot{\hat{r}}}{\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})}$. Notice that the unit vector $\frac{\dot{\hat{r}}}{\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})}$ indicating the *tangent to the trajectory of P* may be denoted by, say $\hat{\theta}$, for brevity.

The case of uniform circular planar motion is obtained by setting $\dot{r}=0$ and $\ddot{\theta}=0$ which corresponds to the case in the OP, wherein the arc length travelled by $P$ is given by $s=r\theta$.

---

$\underline{\textit{Answers to the questions in the OP:}}$

1. The variable $v$ referred to in the OP is *not* the speed but the *signed magnitude* of the velocity. In other words, consider the force due to gravity on a material particle of mass $m$, expressed in the preferred coordinate system of a reference frame which is oriented such that the constant unit vector $\hat{k}$ is directed vertically downwards, so that the force due to gravity is $\vec{F}_\text{gravity}=-mg\hat{k}$. In this expression, $-mg$ is the *signed magnitude* or *component* of the force, while $mg=|\vec{F}_\text{gravity}|:=\|\vec{F}_\text{gravity}\|$ is the *magnitude* or *norm* so that we can write $\vec{F}_\text{gravity}=-|\vec{F}_\text{gravity}|\hat{k}$. If we denote ${F}_\text{gravity}:=-mg$, then $\vec{F}_\text{gravity}=-|\vec{F}_\text{gravity}|\hat{k}={F}_\text{gravity}\hat{k}=-mg\hat{k}$. Similarly, if the position vector of the material particle is given by $\vec{r}=r(\cos\theta\hat{i}+\sin\theta\hat{j})$ executing the planar circular motion $\dot{r}\equiv0$ with the angular speed $\omega:=\dot{\theta}$, then the variable $v:=\omega r$ in the OP expresses the velocity of the material particle as $\vec{v}=v(-sin\theta\hat{i}+\cos\theta\hat{j})$. In this case, the arc length or distance travelled by the material particle as a function of the angle $\theta$ is given by $s=r\theta$. Note that $\|\vec{v}\|:=|v|=|\omega r|$.
2. A similar explanation provides an understanding of the reason why $a=\alpha r$ where $\alpha:=\ddot{\theta}$, since $\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{r}+(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{\theta}\dot{r})\frac{\dot{\hat{r}}}{\text{norm}(\dot{\hat{r}})}$.

The questions in the OP arise from the conflating the definition of the *magnitude* or *norm* of a Eulcidean vector with that of the *signed magnitude* or *components* of the vector.

---

$\underline{\textit{Learning value:}}$

In general, the time derivative of a vector of constant magnitude is perpendicular to the vector. Therefore, $\vec{r} \cdot \dot{\vec{r}} = r \hat{r} \cdot (\dot{r} \hat{r} + r \dot{\hat{r}})$, so that $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v} =  r \dot{r}$. This idea is crucial to developing kinematic relationships in certain analyses.